Add machine Ubuntu to AD windows
I come to ask for help, I am studying data network management and I have to add a linux computer to a windows domain, the truth is I have no knowledge about it, any documentation that you can recommend me or any help you can give me will be well received.
At the moment I have a version of Ubuntu 24.02, and I have a server with the domain controller, according to what little I have investigated I have to add on the client computer some commands to download to the client computer the necessary packages (apt install realmd samba samba-common krb5-user sssd adcli
) to join the computer to domain, I perform the steps but at the end of the process of joining domain I can see that from my client I can see the users I have in the active directory (user id), I can also see the domain to which I am joined by the command (realm list) but if I try to enter with any of these tells me that the authentication failed.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to access the Ubuntu computer using SSH?

If you are adding any computer to a AD then it is the AD you want to learn about not the machine you are adding. That comes after you understand how the AD works.  This being a Ubuntu question and answer site you need to ask a question and give enough details that it can be answered. You have not done that. What version of Ubuntu? What have you already tried? Just 2 things that are missing from this question.

"a linux computer". we ONLY provide support for Ubuntu. 90% of this problem is on the windows end too. You did not find a how to online?! Because I am 100% sure Microsoft has one in their knowledgebase.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a request for a tutorial, not an answerable question.
